# android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #99: Binary XML file line #99: Error inflating class android.widget.ProgressBar

Tags: java, android, xml

I'm trying to add Progressbar in my xml file. This progressbar will be shown as soon as user enters data in the three fields and clicks on "Submit" button and then new Activity will start.

Here's Logcat main error line

> Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.hadithapp/com.example.hadithapp.AddHadithDetailActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #99: Binary XML file line #99: Error inflating class android.widget.ProgressBar

Here's the progressbar xml code

```
<ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/interminate_progress_bar"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:indeterminate="true"
    android:visibility="visible"
    android:theme="@style/ProgressBarTheme"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"/>
```

Here's the style xml code

```
<style name="ProgressBarTheme">
    <item name="android:backgroundTint">@drawable/progress_bar_bg</item>
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/progress_bar_bg</item>
</style>
```

Here's @drawable/progress_bar_bg code

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shape="rectangle">

<corners android:radius="360dp"/>
<solid android:color="@color/colorPrimary"/>

</shape>
```

I didn't know what causes ERROR. But when I removed the theme line in my progress_bar xml code, the ERROR removed.

Still I don't get why progressbar theme doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

When I removed line android:theme="@style/ProgressBarTheme", the ERROR vanished.

But I wanted to get progressbar with circular background as upwork has.And I got it by adding mProgressbar.setBackground(getDrawable(R.drawable.progress_bar_bg)); line of code programmatically. :)

Comment: If this is not the answer to your question, please don't post is as an anwer.

Answer (score 0):

Change `android:theme="@style/ProgressBarTheme"` to `style="@style/ProgressBarTheme"`

Comment: I did but same ERROR.

Comment: I just resolved this error by adding below line programmatically mProgressbar.setBackground(getDrawable(R.drawable.progress_bar_bg));